# Image accessibility issues when creating a gallery

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a photo gallery by storing photos in a gallery database and pulling them out when appropriate.

However, I ran into the problem of how to publicly expose the pictures in urls. In my template, I return a the url of the photo which turns out to be images/photo.jpg. However in my development server, when I put in the url 192.0.0.1:8000/images/photo.jpg (it doesn't exist), I can't view the image. Is there any way to make the url/image accessible through the url provided by the object without manually tampering with urls.py? If not, why does Django provide the .url field? Is this the only a recommended url field then?

My View:

```
def gallery(request):
    base_gallery = gall.objects.get(name="base")
    base_list = base_gallery.photos.all()
    return render_to_response('gallery.html',
        {'list_of_images':base_list},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    )
```

Template:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block body_content %}

{% for photo in list_of_images %}
    {{ photo.image.url }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    source_descr = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')


class gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(photo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings file, what is the value you have given for `MEDIA_URL`, if it is `/media/`
check the following url.

192.0.0.1:8000/**media**/images/photo.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I added '/media/' to MEDIA_URL and unfortunately. 'myobject.ImageField.url' just changed to '/media/images/myimage.jpg'